# Having to push Enter 3 times before showing output in Eclipse

Tags: java

I wrote a program in Java in Eclipse for user to input SSN and Output reads if valid or not. My program works, it just makes me hit Enter 3 times before showing the output of SSN’s validity. What did I do wrong? At first I was using Scanner System in, but then tried Buffered reader, still having to push Enter 3times[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBXMT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use images for your code. No one can work with that and chances are, the link you provided will be worthless in a week from now. Always enter the pertinent code into your post.

You have to hit enter three times because you are asking for input three times. Every `reader.readLine()` requires input and or an entry.

You can still use a Scanner object if you want...it might go something like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String ssn = "";
while (ssn.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print("Enter SSN in the format of: DDD-DD-DDDD -> ");
    // Get User input and remove any possible whitespaces
    ssn = input.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    // Make what was entered follow the desired format of: DDD-DD-DDDD (where D is a digit)
    if (!ssn.matches("\\d{3}\\-\\d{2}\\-\\d{4}")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Social Security Number (" + ssn + ")!. Try again...");
        ssn = "";
    }
}
 
System.out.println("You Supplied: " + ssn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix the code with the answer I received, thanks again! Here is fixed code, tried to upload under comments, but was too long.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SocialSecurityPracticeCh4 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Create a scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String ssn;

    
    //Prompt user to enter a social security number 
    System.out.print("Enter a social security number in the format DDD - DD - DDDD: ");
    ssn = input.nextLine();
    char dash = ssn.charAt(0);
    
    boolean isValid = ssn.length() == 11;
    
    if (isValid) 
    System.out.println(ssn + " is a valid social security number.");
    
    else
     System.out.println(ssn + " is an invalid social security number.");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).